# Always getting PandaSQLException: (sqlite3.OperationalError) near "(": syntax error whenever running a query

Tags: python, sql, pandas, pandasql

I have a csv and there are two columns in it that have null values, one is "industry" and the other is "nps score". I am trying to impute these null values using sql function isnull(), to replace them with a string "missing". However, whenever I tried the query, it gives out errors below:

```
PandaSQLException: (sqlite3.OperationalError) near ",": syntax error 
[SQL: 'SELECT * \n        FROM raw_data \n        WHERE "Industry", "NPS Score" IS NULL;'] 
(Background on this error at: http://sqlalche.me/e/e3q8)
```

I looked it up online but one answer suggests to delete symbols that might cause format error(which I checked and don't think any symbols do wrong), and the other suggests this is a version error, the pandasql makes the mistake and there's no way to fix it.

My ERROR-triggering query goes like:

```
    import pandasql

    from pandasql import sqldf

    import pandas as pd

    q = """
        SELECT "Industry" ISNULL("Industry", "missing")
        FROM raw_data
        WHERE "Industry" IS NULL;
        """

    pysqldf(q)
```

and it WORKed when the query is very simple, such as:

```
   q = """
       SELECT *
       FROM raw_data
       WHERE "Industry" IS NULL OR "NPS Score" IS NULL ;
       """
   pysqldf(q)
```

I tried multiple changes on the code, but I just couldn't fix this error. Could anyone help me out?

I expect the result to be, when I input pysqldf(q), the query will update my data so that in the column "Industry" as well as "NPS score", all null values will be replaced by the string "missing". And I would like it to be written in (preferably) pandasql, if not then sql, then pandas. For now the query that could run without error could only show me data with "Industry" or "NPS score" being null.

full version of error:

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
OperationalError                          Traceback (most recent call last)
/opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/sqlalchemy/engine/base.py in _execute_context(self, dialect, constructor, statement, parameters, *args)
   1192                         parameters,
-> 1193                         context)
   1194         except BaseException as e:

/opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/sqlalchemy/engine/default.py in do_execute(self, cursor, statement, parameters, context)
    508     def do_execute(self, cursor, statement, parameters, context=None):
--> 509         cursor.execute(statement, parameters)
    510 

OperationalError: near "(": syntax error

The above exception was the direct cause of the following exception:

OperationalError                          Traceback (most recent call last)
/opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/pandasql/sqldf.py in __call__(self, query, env)
     60             try:
---> 61                 result = read_sql(query, conn)
     62             except DatabaseError as ex:

/opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/pandas/io/sql.py in read_sql(sql, con, index_col, coerce_float, params, parse_dates, columns, chunksize)
    396             coerce_float=coerce_float, parse_dates=parse_dates,
--> 397             chunksize=chunksize)
    398 

/opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/pandas/io/sql.py in read_query(self, sql, index_col, coerce_float, parse_dates, params, chunksize)
   1062 
-> 1063         result = self.execute(*args)
   1064         columns = result.keys()

/opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/pandas/io/sql.py in execute(self, *args, **kwargs)
    953         """Simple passthrough to SQLAlchemy connectable"""
--> 954         return self.connectable.execute(*args, **kwargs)
    955 

/opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/sqlalchemy/engine/base.py in execute(self, object, *multiparams, **params)
    941         if isinstance(object, util.string_types[0]):
--> 942             return self._execute_text(object, multiparams, params)
    943         try:

/opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/sqlalchemy/engine/base.py in _execute_text(self, statement, multiparams, params)
   1103             parameters,
-> 1104             statement, parameters
   1105         )

/opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/sqlalchemy/engine/base.py in _execute_context(self, dialect, constructor, statement, parameters, *args)
   1199                 cursor,
-> 1200                 context)
   1201 

/opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/sqlalchemy/engine/base.py in _handle_dbapi_exception(self, e, statement, parameters, cursor, context)
   1412                     sqlalchemy_exception,
-> 1413                     exc_info
   1414                 )

/opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/sqlalchemy/util/compat.py in raise_from_cause(exception, exc_info)
    264     cause = exc_value if exc_value is not exception else None
--> 265     reraise(type(exception), exception, tb=exc_tb, cause=cause)
    266 

/opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/sqlalchemy/util/compat.py in reraise(tp, value, tb, cause)
    247         if value.__traceback__ is not tb:
--> 248             raise value.with_traceback(tb)
    249         raise value

/opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/sqlalchemy/engine/base.py in _execute_context(self, dialect, constructor, statement, parameters, *args)
   1192                         parameters,
-> 1193                         context)
   1194         except BaseException as e:

/opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/sqlalchemy/engine/default.py in do_execute(self, cursor, statement, parameters, context)
    508     def do_execute(self, cursor, statement, parameters, context=None):
--> 509         cursor.execute(statement, parameters)
    510 

OperationalError: (sqlite3.OperationalError) near "(": syntax error [SQL: '\n    SELECT Industry isnull(Industry, "missing")\n    FROM raw_data\n    WHERE Industry IS NULL;\n    '] (Background on this error at: http://sqlalche.me/e/e3q8)

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

PandaSQLException                         Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-52-6f489fcb4e65> in <module>
      8     """
      9 
---> 10 pysqldf(q)

<ipython-input-19-210746dc5675> in <lambda>(q)
      7 path1 = '/home/centos/data/kpt2_renewal/Renewals_Data_Pull_07302019_Raw_Data.csv'
      8 df1 = pd.read_csv(path1)
----> 9 pysqldf = lambda q: sqldf(q, globals())
     10 raw_data = df1
     11 q = """

/opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/pandasql/sqldf.py in sqldf(query, env, db_uri)
    154     >>> sqldf("select avg(x) from df;", locals())
    155     """
--> 156     return PandaSQL(db_uri)(query, env)

/opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/pandasql/sqldf.py in __call__(self, query, env)
     61                 result = read_sql(query, conn)
     62             except DatabaseError as ex:
---> 63                 raise PandaSQLException(ex)
     64             except ResourceClosedError:
     65                 # query returns nothing

PandaSQLException: (sqlite3.OperationalError) near "(": syntax error [SQL: '\n    SELECT Industry isnull(Industry, "missing")\n    FROM raw_data\n    WHERE Industry IS NULL;\n    '] (Background on this error at: http://sqlalche.me/e/e3q8)
```

Comment: are you able to solve this issue?